# pointcloud2 data

Tags: ros, messages, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm currently using kinect to receive image message and pointcloud2 message and make a depth and image with message information.

Then,I want to do some classification and label each pointcloud data and send back as ros message.

when I send back this pointcloud data that has label for each point as message.

How should I have this label information??

Thank you

Min

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10886/pointcloud2-data/) by [ros_beginner](https://answers.ros.org/users/819/ros_beginner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-08-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One possible solution is to add a new field to the pcl::PointCloud datatype (that is, create a custom point type in PCL).
There is a tutorial on how to do this on the PCL website:
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php

Then, you would simply publish this new pointcloud with an additional custom label field.

---

Originally posted by [Helen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1033/helen/) with karma: 261 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1